# Crash on kfree call (inside a kernel module)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, free, kernel-module

I have this code

```
int64_t ret;
char *fmt = "\n\n\n%s\n\n\n";
char *s;

s = kmalloc(13, GFP_KERNEL);
memcpy(s, "Hello world!\0", 13);

__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movq %2, %%rdi;"
    "movq %1, %%rsi;"
    "movq $2, %%rax;"

    "call printk;"
    "movq %%rax, %0;"

    : "=r" (ret)
    : "r" (s), "r" (fmt)
    :
);

__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movq %0, %%rdi;"
    "movq $1, %%rax;"
    "call kfree;"

    :
    : "r" (s)
    :
);

return ret;
```

which crashes on the `kfree` call. It must be something silly, but I can't find out what it is. What is the problem?

EDIT: "Crashes" == The kernel module triggers an Oops.

EDIT: It seems to work just fine if I use `m` instead of `r`. But why?

Comment: It seems likely that those registers do not hold the values you think they hold. Is there a reason you have to use inlined assembly here rather than just writing your code in C?

Comment: @EricMelski I'm going to write some pure asm so I'm testing with this instead. According to docs, RDI holds the 1st argument and RAX holds the number of arguments that the call accepts.

Comment: Why don't you start from testing the same in userspace using a step by step debugging?

Comment: @user16653 I could, but userspace and kernelspace are really different (even the registers used for args doesn't match), and I'm not sure if that will confuse me even more. Anyways, what would I'd be looking for?

Comment: Different in what respect? Never noticed any difference, at least when amd64 is concerned. :)

Comment: @alexandernst Mind you, you're using intra-kernel ABI (which is just a normal C abi) not a system call/vdso ABI (which is indeed different, as could be expected).

Comment: @user16653 Ah, indeed, you're right. I mixed syscalls with <normal> calls.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the generated assembly code (use `-S` option to `gcc`) to see exactly what is happening.

I am guessing that the problem is that you didn't specify the correct clobbers for the `printk` block. Remember that certain registers may be freely used by a called function. The compiler doesn't process the contents of the inline asm block, so it doesn't know it has a `call` inside. It expects that registers not specified as output or clobber will come out unchanged from the asm block. Thus, I assume the compiler caches the variable `s` in a register that is destroyed by the `printk` or your use of `rax`, `rdi` and `rsi` which you also don't tell the compiler. Note that there are specific register constraints, so you could use those instead of moving the arguments around in assembly.

Also note that `rax` (actually `al`) is only used for varargs and stdargs functions, and even then it should just contain the number of arguments passed via sse vector (`xmm`) registers, not the total number. See the x86-64 ABI docs for more information.

Finally, if you really want to write asm code, you should consider writing standalone asm module instead of C if possible. You could save yourself some headache. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668403/writing-x86-64-linux-kernel-module-in-assembler) for an example.